# Loading a ASPX CSS file into a telerik StyleSheetManager declared inside a master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

How do you load a ASPX CSS file into a telerik StyleSheetManager declared inside a master page?
Is there something like a scriptManagerProxy equivalent for CSS and Telerik's style sheet manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the reference to the stylesheet manager using a static method:

```
RadStyleSheetManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).StyleSheets.Add(..);
```

Similar to the `ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page)` method.